# Htaccess 301 redirect: looking for specific variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have this at the moment:

RewriteRule ^/?word/(.*) /display.php?mid=$1 [L,R=301]

Which will turns:http://testpp.peoplepulse.com.au/word/testvar into http://testpp.peoplepulse.com.au/display.php?mid=testvar.

How can i search for a string of 16 characters/numbers instead of the word 'word'?

Answer (score 0):

If by characters you mean letters:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9]{16}/([^/]*) /display.php?mid=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

If you mean "any character":

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]{16}/([^/]*) /display.php?mid=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: So got it working using: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*) /display.php?mid=$1 [L,R=301] - but it required a trailing slash after string entered into the url...anyone know how to do for both a trailing and non trailing?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}]/(.*) display.php?mid=$1 [L,R=301]
```